# What's the best IPAM solution for Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

Recently just got a new job as an azure admin. The new company doesn't have a huge network but it's spread out over multiple environments and subscriptions. I have been using Network watcher to view topologies of the network but would like to create some IP management. In my last place, we used SolarWinds IPAM which was great. Is there anything similar to that on Azure, struggling to find anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is not any solution like On-prem IPAM in Azure, But this Requirement has started to build last year and still in progress by Microsoft Architects , Once it will in production, this to become a SaaS/PaaS product that will help all of customers manage their IP Address. You can track their progress and ask question and contribute as well from this [***GitHub***](https://github.com/Azure/ipam) Link